# Type annotation for handling modules

Tags: python-3.x, module, typing, python-3.8

Suppose that we had the following Python script:

```
from assets import module_1, module_2, module_3


def get_help(module) -> None:
    """Returns short message about module."""
    print(f"Name: {module.__name__}")
    print(f"Details: {module.__doc__}")


for m in (module_1, module_2, module_3):
    get_help(m)
```

What would be the appropriate type annotation for the argument `module`? I can't see anything useful from a quick look at the `typing` module.

Comment: @TrebledJ Ah, yes. I had looked for a question like that, even perhaps with the same keywords. Does this mean I should delete my question?

Comment: Not necessarily, people may still come across it and be redirected to the other question.